# Side by side algorithms with vertical line

Tags: vertical-alignment

How can i produce this [image: scheme] in latex. My question is about the framework to put it inside,figure,algorithm,tabular? And how i can separate it with this verical line

Comment: Please give us some bigger picture! You should also give us some code of what you have tried. We do not know which kind of algorithm you are using and we would have to type several lines in order to guess around a bit. Thank you.

Comment: your illustration would be more easily understood if it included only the relevant part, and not the rest of the (mostly empty) page.  there are some hints on generating such output in the question [How do you crop an attached PDF?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1799/579).  using the `standalone` package and/or the command `\thispagestyle{empty}` after `\begin{document}` are also effective in excluding extraneous blank space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document} 
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}    
    \begin{minipage}{5cm}
            \begin{algorithmic}[1]
                \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}
                \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
                \While{$r\not=0$}
                \State $a\gets b$
                \State $b\gets r$
                \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
                \EndWhile
                \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is b}
                \EndProcedure
            \end{algorithmic}
    \end{minipage}
    &
    \begin{minipage}{5cm}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}
        \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
        \While{$r\not=0$}
        \State $a\gets b$
        \State $b\gets r$
        \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
        \EndWhile
        \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is b}
        \EndProcedure
    \end{algorithmic}
    \end{minipage}
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The only issue is that this is not centered in the text.It is left alligned. Also, how the numbering can be disable?

Comment: @curious Add a `\centering` in front of `\begin{table}` and if you prefer also in front of each `\begin{algorithm}`. The second point is a completely different topic. I do not know that package but copied something to help here. Please read the documentation, if you are even using `algpseudocode`.